# Setting cargo.tomcat.valve values in a build.gradle file

Tags: tomcat, build.gradle, cargo, tomcat-valve

**What I am trying to do**: 
I want to add a AccessLogValve to the tomcat server.xml so that I can log custom header values. (ref: https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-can-i-log-custom-request-headers-using-the-tomcat-access-log-valve/)

**Problem I am having**: 
Every-time the gradle is run it creates new server.xml.  I want to add a `cargo.tomcat.valve` container property however I cannot find a format that works.

The valve I want to add is the `Access Log Valve` https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve

A failed example is `containerProperties ['cargo.tomcat.valve'] = 'className=org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve| pattern=combined'`

I have tried various versions of the above but none seem to work.

I can see that the maven example is

```
<cargo.tomcat.valve.stuckthread>
    className=org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve|
    threshold=60
</cargo.tomcat.valve.stuckthread>
```

ref:
https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/apidocs/org/codehaus/cargo/container/tomcat/TomcatPropertySet.html#CUSTOM_VALVE

However I cannot find a way to add custom valves using gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the study, we figured out that the access log updates in server.xml file for tomcat can work with the cargo plugin version >= 2.3 (the current latest one is 2.7.1 as of 30-Apr-2020)

The example for updating the valve in build.gradle should be as below:

```html
containerProperties  = [
            'cargo.tomcat.ajp.port' : 8050,
            'cargo.tomcat.valve' : "className=org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve|pattern=%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b %{X-Custom-Header}i|directory=logs|prefix=localhost_access_log.|suffix=.txt"
    ]
```